# IPv6 on Linksys Velop, small issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6, prefix

I have set my router to automatic IPv6 but it doesn't seem to work on IPv6-test.com.

When I type `ipconfig` in cmd prompt (administrator) I get the IPv6 address starting with fe80 (and it's mentioned as the link-local address, I'm not sure what that means either).

So what do I plug in prefix and prefix length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check with your ISP. Different ISPs have chosen to support IPv6 in different ways. There may even be some ISPs that still don't support it (but there are ways to work around that via tunneling).

You can't just use any IPv6 prefix. You have to use a prefix that your ISP has been assigned, that your ISP then delegates to you.

Your ISP should be able to tell you whether they support IPv6 and how to configure your router to work with their IPv6 infrastructure.

Edited to add: A prefix is the first part of an IPv6 address. In some cases it's the entire first half of the address. It represents your network. The rest of the address after the prefix is the part that specifies a particular host (computer / device) on that network. The big routers at ISPs have route tables based on prefixes. They only look at the prefix to know which way to send traffic to reach your network. Once the traffic reaches the router that "owns" (has been assigned/delegated) that prefix, then that final router is responsible for looking at the rest of the address and sending that traffic to the particular computer it's addressed to.

fe80:: is the link-local prefix, which is basically the IPv6 equivalent of the 169.254.0.0/16 link-local subnet from IPv4. It's for self-assigned IP addresses that can only be used on the local LAN and cannot be routed to the public Internet. It exists so you can use IPv6 on an isolated LAN with no Internet connection without having to know anything about IPv6. It has other uses as well which are probably beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Could you please explain what a prefix is, most websites show prefixes starting with 2001 or something similar, but mine seems to start with fe80

Comment: @OneQuestion Okay I've updated my Answer to cover your followup question.